# Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

iam not able to update any thing on my pie, iam getting the following error
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'

nameserver in  resolv.conf is  8.8.8.8

this is the ping result root@raspberrypi:/etc# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

i have previously installed piehole in my pie, but after that i have formatted the memory card and installed the fresh os. Please suggest any fix.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is super old but in case anyone else stumbles here from google, my /etc/resolv.conf file only had 127.0.0.1 as the dns, after adding 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 I was able to upgrade.

In order to update the file you need to change the dhcpd file:

`sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

add this to the bottom of the file to add the cloudflare dns servers:

`static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1`

or alternatively the google domain servers

`static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8`

then just restart the dhcp service and you should be good to proceed with your upgrades:

`sudo service dhcpcd restart`

If you have 8.8.8.8 already in the config you could try the cloudflare ones, it's possible you just need to restart the service though.

Comment: Super old? at two months when the answer was written? :D

I suppose that would be the perspective of youth ...

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue when attempting apt-upgrade but I could ping google and access the internet just fine. Turns out it was related to my VPN (mullvad) turning the vpn service off, upgrading, and restarting it worked for me.
Answering here because I couldn't see this solution anywhere when searching.